# Get Machine epsilon in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, epsilon

This seems like a question better directed at those with some programming experience rather than just general Excel users, hence my asking on here as opposed to Superuser.

Is there any way, preferably through a function, to return epsilon (i.e. the smallest non-zero number representable in Excel's calculations)? If it's not retrievable through a function, is there a quick way to calculate it through a compact function?

To be clear, I'm not looking for a VBA-based solution, I'd like an Excel formula/ spreadsheet based solution that does not require running macros.

My searches online have mostly turned up discussions on how to display the symbol Epsilon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excel always operates on IEEE doubles.

A non-VBA expression that will get you the smallest non-denormalized floating point number greater than 0 is

```
=2^-1022
```

Machine epsilon, on the other hand, is the smallest number that can be added to 1 and result in a number that is greater than 1.  For double precision it is given by

```
=2^-52
```

Comment: Right, and put that in a defined name if you need it more than once.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft defines its floating point number precision limits for XL. The smallest floating point number is listed as 2.2250738585072E-308 in the [Microsoft support article ID: 78113](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113). When I enter this number in my spreadsheet it actually stores a floating point 0, but if I store 2.2250738585073E-308, (I added 1 to the least significant digit) I can see all the digits. I see you asked for a machine epsilon, but since you are using XL, what you will really see is the C/C++ floating point library epsilon. See the [Microsoft Developer Network xlfRegister (Form 1) topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687900%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You may write a VBA subroutine like:

```
 Public Sub ComputeMachineEpsilon()
     Dim g, ex, eps As Double
     Dim i As Long
     g = 1
     i = 0
     Do
        i = i + 1
        g = g / 2
        ex = g * 0.98 + 1
        ex = ex - 1
        If ex > 0 Then eps = ex
     Loop While ex > 0

     MsgBox ("No. of Iterations " & i)
     MsgBox ("Machine Epsilon is " & eps)

    End Sub
```

But on my machine it gives 2,22E-16, and it's strange because I can write `=2^-113` in a cell and get 9,62965E-35.

**EDIT**:

```
=1*(0,5-0,4-0,1)
```

I get: -2,78E-17

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I was hoping for a non-VBA based solution, i.e. one that returns Epsilon using Excel functions or spreadsheet functionality. I would prefer to not have to run any macros. Sorry I wasn't clear about this. I have updated my question to clarify this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
=2^if(1+2^-49<>1,NA(),if(1+2^-48<>1,-48,if(1+2^-47<>1,-47,NA())))
```

The above assume epsilon is an integral power of 2 in the range -48 to -47, otherwise returns `NA()`. On Excel 2021 this returns 2^-47. Expand the number of nested `IFs` following the same pattern to capture larger or smaller possible epsilon ranges, as needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).