# Excel machine epsilon comparison

Tags: excel, epsilon

So I learned that machine epsilon in Excel is 2^(-1022) [Get Machine epsilon in Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380108/get-machine-epsilon-in-microsoft-excel)

Suppose I have in cell A1: `=1+2^-1022`

`=1=A1` returns `TRUE`

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should read all the comments to that question. Your answer is there:

> Microsoft defines its floating point number precision limits for XL.
>   The smallest floating point number is listed as 2.2250738585072E-308
>   in the Microsoft support article ID: 78113. When I enter this number
>   in my spreadsheet it actually stores a floating point 0, but if I
>   store 2.2250738585073E-308, (I added 1 to the least significant digit)
>   I can see all the digits. I see you asked for a machine epsilon, but
>   since you are using XL, what you will really see is the C/C++ floating
>   point library epsilon. See the Microsoft Developer Network xlfRegister
>   (Form 1) topic.

Comment: If you endter `=2^-1022` adn then format the cell as `0.00000000000000E+0` you can see it displays `2.22507385850720E-308` and then if you paste special values into a cell formatted as General you get `2.2250738585072E-308`